# Can I pass table valued parameters to a stored procedure with PetaPoco?

Tags: table-valued-parameters, petapoco

I'm trying to use PetaPoco for a project that has some stored procedures.  Most of them work fine, however, we have a couple where the stored procedure is expecting an IntList which is a User-Defined Table Type.

I haven't found a way to do this, and I hope I'm just missing something obvious.  The current work around that I have is to copy the stored procedure code from SQL into a string and then execute that against my PetaPoco database:

```
public IEnumerable<UserComments> GetComments(IEnumerable<int> userIds)
{
   using(var db = new Database(connection))
   {
      db.Fetch<UserComments>(new Sql("select UserId, Comment from Comments where UserId in    (@0)", userIds);
   }
}
```

Comment: How would you normally call it through ado.net?

Comment: Did You get PetaPoco to working with TableValue Param When I try pass sqlparam I alway get error Column, parameter, or variable @0. : Cannot find data type Structured. Can You show how call fetch with table value param.

Comment: I think I did, but since it's been almost 2 years now, I don't even know what code I was working on, so I can't give you much help

Comment: Thank You any way here is my problem/solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019412/pass-table-value-param-to-stored-procedure-using-petapoco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a SqlParameter directly in.
eg

```
db.Fetch<User>("EXECUTE getUser @0", new SqlParameter(,,,,));
```

So you should be able to call it like you would directly through ADO.net.