# Pass table value param to stored procedure using PetaPoco

Tags: c#-4.0, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, petapoco, table-valued-parameters

For while I am trying to call SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure using PetaPoco.

My stored procedure accepts a table valued parameter.

How I can call the stored procedure in petapoco with table value param?

Here what I am trying to do:

```
var db = new PetaPoco.Database("repikaciskaBaza");

DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn id = table.Columns.Add("id", type: typeof(Int32));

for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["id"] = i;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

var param = new SqlParameter();
param.DbType = DbType.Object;
param.ParameterName = "@art_id";

param.SqlValue = table;

var lista = db.Query<pocoArts>(";exec dbo.test_sporc_param @0", param);
```

This code gives me an exception :

> The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect.
>   Parameter 3 ("@0"): Data type 0x62 (sql_variant) has an invalid type for type-specific metadata.

If I set parametar ty value

```
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

Then I get exception like

```
The table type parameter '@0' must have a valid type name.
```

When I define my param like

```
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            param.SqlValue = table;
            param.ParameterName = "@art_id";
            param.TypeName = SqlDbType.Structured.ToString();
```

Then I get exception

> Column, parameter, or variable @0. : Cannot find data type Structured.

How I can define `SqlParam` with table valued param so I can send it whit data to SQL Server?

**Solution**:

```
var param = new SqlParameter();
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured; // According to marc_s
param.SqlValue = table; 
param.ParameterName = "@art_id";
param.TypeName = "dbo.typ_art_id"; // this is TYP from SQL Server database it needs to be equal to type defined in SQL Server not type of param
```

Comment: While I can't say the above doesn't work.  I couldn't get a named parameter working in my solution.  I ended up just doing a @0 instead.

db.Query<Thing>("INNER JOIN @0 rowIds ON ...", param).ToList()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [relevant MSDN documentation on table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), you should use:

```
var param = new SqlParameter();
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

The `SqlDbType.Structured` is the key to this. Don't use `DbType.Object`.

Comment: I did it and Now I have different exception